# ''s cannot be resolved'' How can i solve this error?

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner with a weak understanding of Java. I use Dr.Java and I get this error:

```
     "S cannot be resolved"
```

With this Java program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HDtest5

{
    public static int countWords(String str) {
        String words[] = str.split(" ");
        int count = words.length;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
        String sentence = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");
    }

    {
        while (true) // have created infinite loop
        {

            if (s.equals("quit"))
            // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop

            {

                String[] words = s.split(" "); // get the individual words
                System.out.println("#words = " + words.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(s + "word[" + i + words[i] + " nchars = " + words[i].length());

            }
            System.out.println(s); // to Print string
            System.out.println(s.length()); // to print Entered string's length

        }
    }
}
```

What causes this error message? 
I thought all the strings called 's' should work together without any problems. Could you please help me to find out what is wrong with it? Thank you very much for any help, its much appreciated!

Ps. Just to be more clear, the purpose of my program is to output total number of characters, characters of each word and a number of words of the text entered in text window (scanner). The code should work perfectly, except this 's' string problem which makes the chunks of code not work together.

Comment: You haven't defined a `s` variable

Comment: on which line the error is???

Comment: Just FYI, your `if (s.equals(quit))` does not take you out of the loop.

Comment: Guessing `s`is meant to be referring to `String sentence`? You need to use the same variable name in both places...

Comment: Your code doesn't seems good, there must be compilation errors in this code other then `s`.

Comment: The same error message appears for a few lines, lines 25, 31, 34, 37 and 38. Before my code worked fine and all the chunks of code worked together, but then when i added a part of code which counts the words, the code stopped working and recognizing my strings.

Comment: Start formatting your code using proper indentation. Your `{   while (true) // have created infinite loop` code is at level class fields and methods which makes it initialization block (which will be moved to constructor) which I am not sure if you wanted. Also where did you declare `s`?

Comment: There's also a closing bracket in the wrong position, terminating the main block too early. If you had used proper indentation this would be much easier to spot.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, i finally found the right answer, as a total java beginner i didn't declare s in my code, which is strange because before my code was working without it. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to use the `sentence` variable instead.
And you don't read the variable for each iteration of your while loop.

Maybe you wanted to have more something like that.

```
public class HDtest5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) { // have created infinite loop
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");

            if (sentence.equals("quit")) { // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop
                break;
            } else {
                String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // get the individual words
                System.out.println("#words = " + words.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(sentence + "word[" + i + words[i] + " nchars = " + words[i].length());

            }
            System.out.println(sentence); // to Print string
            System.out.println(sentence.length()); // to print Entered string's length

        }
        in.close();
    }

    private static int countWords(String str) {
        String words[] = str.split(" ");
        int count = words.length;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you have to first declare a variable *before* you may use it.

There is missing a line of code like this:

```
String s;
```

BTW, you probably want to use `sentence` instead of `s`, as other people noticed. The possible value `"quit"` will be in the `sentence` variable.

---

By *declaring a variable*:

```
String personName;
```

you say the compiler:

> From now on, understand `personName` as a piece of memory capable of storing a `String`.

The compiler will do a great work for you - it will not let you assign to `personName` anything else (like `int`), and if you made a typo and write `personMame` somewhere, you will find it immediately and not very late in runtime where you don't know why your code does not work, like in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

you have not declared `s` in your code .Write something like this,`String s=null;` just in the beginning of the `main()` method and then give it some value later in your code

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error becuase you have not declared any variable S but you are using this in your if condition. Also you have wrongly placed the { } braces. 
change main method  to below:

Note: your prog is running in infinte loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(s) + " words.");

    while (true) // have created infinite loop
    {

        if (s.equals("quit"))
        // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop

        {

            String[] words = s.split(" "); // get the individual words
            System.out.println("#words = " + words.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                System.out.println(s + "word[" + i + words[i]
                        + " nchars = " + words[i].length());

        }
        System.out.println(s); // to Print string
        System.out.println(s.length()); // to print Entered string's length

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out what You want to achievie and fixed Your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HDtest5

{
    public static int countWords(String str) {
        String words[] = str.split(" ");
        int count = words.length;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) // have created infinite loop
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
            String sentence = in.nextLine();
            if (sentence.equals("quit")) {
                // if enterd value is "quit" than it comes out of loop
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("Your sentence has " + countWords(sentence) + " words.");

            String[] words = sentence.split(" "); // get the individual words
            System.out.println("#words = " + words.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
                System.out.println("word[" + i + "] = " + words[i] + " nchars = " + words[i].length());
            }
            System.out.println(sentence); // to Print string
            System.out.println(sentence.length()); // to print Entered string's length
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I already added some sentence variables to my code and it finally works!